# Laravel: The package laravel-elixir does not satisfy its siblings'

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

I wanted to use updated packages and got the error :

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package laravel-elixir does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer laravel-elixir-livereload@1.1.3 wants laravel-elixir@^3.0
```

**package.json** contains:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "laravel-elixir-livereload": "1.1.3",
    "babel-eslint": "5.0.0-beta6",
    "eslint": "1.10.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "3.13.1",
    "laravel-elixir-eslint": "1.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint resources/assets/js/"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `laravel-elixir` 4.0 supports `laravel-elixir-livereload` yet. I got it to work by using a previous version of elixir like so:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "laravel-elixir": "^3.4.3",
    "laravel-elixir-livereload": "^1.1.3"
  }
```